# The Shadow City cools its bones near this water. Where is the next clue?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been searching throughout the Shadow City of the Sunspear in Westeroscraft for weeks now and still have yet to find the next clue.

I have read the books and watched the show and do not believe there is any reference to this in either. I have taken into account that the Water Gardens may also be a possibility but did not find anything there either. While scouring the internet for answers, I also came across the possibility that somewhere in King's Landing may also be called the Shadow City, but have yet to find anything to back that up.

If you have perhaps completed the scavenger hunt, it would be really helpful if you could tell me where (more specifically) to search or at least if I'm on the right track.

Comment: Does "brothels galore" tell you anything? It was mentioned at scifi.stackexchange.com in a question regarding this hunt at Westeroscraft.

Comment: lol, I was just reading AFFC and found a reference that says Sunspear is called the shadow city. It is the "The Captain of Guards" chapter right at the beginning.

Comment: @TLP Ah? Well that could mean the water gardens.

Comment: @Fluttershy Sounds reasonable in the context. I was thinking of some sea or river.

Comment: @Fluttershy the Sunspear and Water Gardens are quite big and as you can imagine, there is water everywhere in both locations. If you could help me narrow down the search area a bit more that would be really helpful

Comment: @bajinga Sadly, I have no experience with Westeroscraft. I do have experience with A Song of Ice and Fire, though. Doran Martell would always sit under a fruit tree to watch the children playing in the Water Gardens. Perhaps there is some sort of orchard-esque area in Westeroscraft's Water Gardens.

Answer (score 1):

I have a suspicion that the sign which contains the clue was either removed someone with the ability to build on the server, or was never put up as an error of the individual(s) who designed the scavenger hunt.

My only reasoning for this speculation is this: While the Water Gardens did make sense for this clue, I have searched it high and low (even in hidden and incomplete areas) and found nothing.  While searching the Shadow City, I came across a small building called the Public Baths which also contained nothing.  The only remaining possibility is the port of the Sunspear, which (you guessed it) contained nothing.

I do not know what happened to the sign, or if I'm just missing it somewhere obvious.  All I do know is that I read the books, I watched the show and nowhere does either reference any water other than the places which I have fully searched (the exception is the public baths, which do not appear in either).

My recommendation to anyone attempting to complete this hunt in the future is to give up. Or you could always risk getting booted from the server for revealing this clue when asking for help.  Either way, I see no point in proceeding further with this.  That is, unless someone has found the next clue in an impossible location and would care to share it.